# Format text using regular expressions

Tags: javascript, formatting

I want to make a question & answers module in my website. I want to use regular expressions to make the plain text written in the questions to look bold when written as **__This text is bold__** or to make it look like a code when written under backticks like 
`'this is a code'`

This is similar to ways used to increase the readibility while asking questions in stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
function applyMarkup(text) {
  return text.replace(/__([^\s\*]+)__/, '<strong>$1</strong>')
      .replace(/`([^\s\*]+)`/, '<code>$1</code>')
}
```

Turns `´Code´ is __great__!` (used forward ticks here) into `<code>Code</code> is <strong>great</strong>!`

Answer (score 0):

```
function markup(string) {
  return string
    .replace(/__(.*?)__/g, '<strong>$1</strong>')
    .replace(/\'(.*?)\'/g, '<code>$1</code>');
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.